# pgfmath does not work

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to use the pgfmath engine, but the result is not what I expect. In this example, I want both lines to have the same length.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[color=blue, very thick] (0,0) -- (2,0);
        \pgfmathparse{ceil(1.7)} % Why is the red line shorter? It should be 2 units in length
        \draw[color=red, very thick] (0,0.5) -- (\pgfmathresult,0.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Sorry if this question seems too stupid, but I don't know what's wrong. Thanks for your help.

Comment: have you tried `{\pgfmathresult}`?

Comment: @daleif This is not the problem here, it's just that `\pgfmathresult` was getting overwitten.

Comment: Use `\pgfmathsetmacro\myceil{ceil(1.7)}` and then `\myceil` instead of `\pgfmathresult`.

Comment: I know it's not how TikZ/PGF works (or LateX in general for that matter) but it would be more intuitive if there was a more clear concept of user namespace/context, in this case that `\pgfmathresult` contains the most recent result of what the user computed in their code, and not the most recent result of whatever TikZ has been doing in the background.

Comment: @Marijn PGF/Ti*k*Z is accepting pull requests: https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf

Answer (score 18, accepted):

PGF is used everywhere in Ti*k*Z. At the point where you invoke `\pgfmathresult`, the result of your calculation has already been overwritten by something from the last `\draw` statement before the point where you used `\pgfmathresult`.

In order to avoid this problem, you can store the the result right after computing it:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[color=blue, very thick] (0,0) -- (2,0);
  \pgfmathparse{ceil(1.7)}
  \let\mylen\pgfmathresult
  % This would also work, but \let means less work to do
  % for TeX (thanks to egreg for the suggestion!)
  % \edef\mylen{\pgfmathresult}
  \draw[color=red, very thick] (0,0.5) -- (\mylen,0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

but there is a shortcut for this, which is to use `\pgfmathsetmacro`:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[color=blue, very thick] (0,0) -- (2,0);
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\mylen}{ceil(1.7)}
  \draw[color=red, very thick] (0,0.5) -- (\mylen,0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Simpler would be `\let\mylen\pgfmathresult`, but `\pgfmathsetmacro` is conceptually better.

Comment: @egreg Indeed you're right, I've put the `\let` technique instead of the `\edef`. Thanks!