# Error using extra y ticks, trying to evaluate it : Package PGF Math Error

Tags: tikz-pgf, axis, ticks

Hello there here is a minimal code :

```
    \documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

    \usepackage{graphics}
    \usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \def\Kg{2}
    \def\w{(3.14159*2)}
    \def\Ttrace{3}

    \begin{axis}[axis x line=bottom, axis y line = left ,
    width=13cm, height=\axisdefaultheight,
    ymax=1.55*\Kg, ymin = 1,
    ytick=\empty,extra y ticks={1.9,\Kg,2.1}, extra y tick labels={$0.95K$,$K$,$1.05K$},extra y tick style={grid=none},
        name=aa,
    xtick=\empty,
    ]

    \addplot[samples=2,domain=0:(\Ttrace+0.1),thick=1pt] { \Kg };
    \addplot[samples=2,domain=0:(\Ttrace+0.1),dashed,thin] { 0.95*\Kg };
    \addplot[samples=2,domain=0:(\Ttrace+0.1),dashed,thin] { 1.05*\Kg };

    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

It produces :
[image]

But I'd like to do is use something like

```
    extra y ticks={0.95*\Kg,\Kg,1.05*\Kg},
```

to try and evaluate the value for the plot.

But if I do I get an error:

```
     Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '0.95*2' as a floating point number, sorry. The unreadable part was near '*2'..
```

Even if I try the messy

```
    extra y ticks={{\pgfmathparse{0.95*\Kg}\pgfmathresult},\Kg,{\pgfmathparse{1.05*\Kg}\pgfmathresult}},
```

I get :

```
   ! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 27.
```

Comment: I deleted my answer because I realized after your comment that it was wrong. Both functions and macros work for me, so it's possible that it is a version difference, and that with the latest version of `pgf`/`pgfplots` what you first tried works fine.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thank you for your answer anyway. How do I use a other version of pgfplot ?

Comment: I don't know if that is what causes it to work for me and not you, it was more or less a stab in the dark. If you add `\pgfversion` and `\pgfplotsversion` in your document, the version numbers will be printed. The method for updating a package depends on which TeX distribution you're using, I can't give a complete answer to that in a comment here (partly because I don't know the complete answer), there are bound to be some questions on the site discussing updating packages though

Answer (score 2):

According to your first error message, `extra y ticks` doesn't seem to be happy with expressions such as `0.95*2`. I don't know if this is expected or a bug, but your idea of using `\pgfmathparse` in order to give `extra y ticks` already-computed values was a good one; you just missed an important point when trying to implement it.

The calculation *per se* (`\pgfmathparse`) relies on TeX operations such as assignments, that don't work in expansion-only contexts; one often says that it is “not expandable” (in contrast, `\pgfmathresult` does work in expansion-only contexts). So, you just need to do the calculation (`\pgfmathparse` or something similar like `\pgfmathsetmacro`) in a place where these operations can be executed, for instance inside your `tikzpicture`, just before the `\begin{axis}`—it could also work in many other places, even before the `tikzpicture`.

Since there are two values to compute and `\pgfmathresult` can only store one result at a given time, we'll use `\pgfmathsetmacro` instead of `\pgfmathparse`, in order to define two macros that store the two results, like this:

```latex
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myextraticki}{0.95*\Kg}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myextratickii}{1.05*\Kg}
```

Note that even with only one value to compute, doing `\pgfmathparse` before the `\begin{axis}` and using `\pgfmathresult` in one of its arguments would be quite risky, because the `\begin{axis}` code could very well overwrite your result in `\pgfmathresult` before it is used—see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/497648/pgfmath-does-not-work) for an example of this error.

It would be possible, though, to do the first calculation, then `\let\firstresult\pgfmathresult`, then do the second calculation, then `\let\secondresult\pgfmathresult`, but that would be less elegant. In other words, you could take the example below and replace the two lines given above with this:

```latex
\pgfmathparse{0.95*\Kg}
\let\myextraticki\pgfmathresult
\pgfmathparse{1.05*\Kg}
\let\myextratickii\pgfmathresult
```

Both files would give exactly the same output. So, let's give the complete solution with `\pgfmathsetmacro` (the more elegant approach):

```latex
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\def\Kg{2}
\def\w{(3.14159*2)}
\def\Ttrace{3}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\myextraticki}{0.95*\Kg}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myextratickii}{1.05*\Kg}

\begin{axis}[axis x line=bottom, axis y line = left,
             width=13cm, height=\axisdefaultheight, ymax=1.55*\Kg, ymin = 1,
             ytick=\empty, extra y ticks={\myextraticki,\Kg,\myextratickii},
             extra y tick labels={$0.95K$,$K$,$1.05K$},
             extra y tick style={grid=none}, name=aa, xtick=\empty]

\addplot[samples=2,domain=0:(\Ttrace+0.1),thick=1pt] { \Kg };
\addplot[samples=2,domain=0:(\Ttrace+0.1),dashed,thin] { 0.95*\Kg };
\addplot[samples=2,domain=0:(\Ttrace+0.1),dashed,thin] { 1.05*\Kg };

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]